# Where can I get this tallit?

Tags: product-recommendation, tallit-gadol

For several months I've been looking for a new weekday tallit, as mine is starting to fall apart (see a previous question about the position of one of the corners for a photo). My personal preference, independent of colour, is to have a somewhat strong stripping pattern. In particular, I am quite fond of a [certain Talitnia pattern,](http://en.talitnia.co.il/products/item/6/pr/?t=000000) although I've not been able to find it. If anyone has had more luck, where, preferably on the internet, did you find it?

Comment: http://en.talitnia.co.il/contact-us/

Comment: @GershonGold, I emailed. I'm waiting to hear back

Answer (score 1):

You can buy it at [MyShofar.com](http://www.myshofar.com/prima-a-a-tallit.html#.VJGQWdKf6jc).

You can also buy it at [ajudaica.com](http://www.ajudaica.com/Prima-AA-Tallit/item259).

Comment: Gershon, I saw MyShofar, but the pattern is different and I highly suspect that the website is really aimed at Messianics.

Comment: http://www.myshofar.com/myshofar-about.html They seem to be normal people. Contact them to verify the pattern at http://www.myshofar.com/contact-us.html

Comment: This link is what really makes me wonder: http://www.myshofar.com/religious-articles/anointing-oils.html

Comment: They have an about us page at http://www.myshofar.com/myshofar-about.html and are in Bnei Brak. You will also see there that MyShofar and ajudaica are the same group

Comment: I know the owners. They're frum. They're actually in Elad now. Started out selling STaM in Bnei Brak.